# Fade out a DIV when a progress bar gets 100% width

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

I've created a "loading div" in my website... When you enter in the website, you just see a black div with a logo and a progress bar in the middle.

The progress bar has been done with CSS3 and JQuery (transitions). When the page loads, the body tag gets a "loaded" class, and the progress bar increases to 100%...

When the progress bar gets the 100% width, the black div dissapears...

I have created this code for making the black div dissapears, but it doesn't work... Can you help me?

```
$(window).load(function () { $('body').addClass('loaded'); });

if($('body').hasClass('loaded')) {
    if($('#progress_bar').width() == '100%'){ $('#black_div').fadeOut('fast'); }
}
```

**NEW PART**

I have implemented the function that you told me and I have created an alert:

```
alert($('#progress_bar').loadingWidth());
```

But when I load the page, the alert displays 0% width. So somehow I have to use that function when the width animations end and the div gets his 100% width. But, how...? timeupdate function? while statement? maybe ajax...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.width()` will return px, so you would need to calculate its width somehow. One way is to check it against its parent element.

Something like this could do the trick:

```
$.fn.Percentage = function(){
    var parent = this.parent();
    return ~~((this.width()/parent.width())*100)+"%";
}
```

and then call it using:

```
if ($("#progress_bar").Percentage() == "100%" ){
 $('#black_div').fadeOut('fast'); 
}
```

Here is an **[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LR7Bg/28/)**

Comment: It doesn't work... I have a progress bar with 0% width. When the page loads, the body tag gets a class: "loaded". So, If I have the bar with transition: width 2s linear; and body.loaded #progress_bar with  width: 100%, the width increases gradually. When it gets 100%, then, the div dissapears... But as I said, It didn't work

Comment: you could use `setTimeout()` to delay the `fadeOut()` untill the progress bar reaches 100%